# Create migrations for models inside egg dependency

Tags: django, django-models, egg

I have a Django project that itself does not have apps. All apps come in through egg dependencies installed in a pyvenv environment.
Those apps have models but do not have 'manage.py' or database settings (just a plain app).

I am now struggling to create the migrations for the apps in the eggs. When I execute 'python manage.py makemigrations' I get 'No changes detected' even though I wiped the DB before. When I then run the server it tells me that I have 13 unapplied migrations from Django core modules such as 'auth', 'sessions' etc. I can apply them running 'python manage.py migrate'.

I tried creating a dummy app, added it to INSTALLED_APPS and added an import of a model from an egg to models.py of that app. Didn't work either, still 'No changes detected'.

Those egg dependencies are apps I created. Is 'egg' the wrong format here? What are the alternatives? Can I tell the 'makemigrations' module where to look? What else could be the cause?

Comment: Are the egg apps included in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Why this migrations not inside eggs in first place?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Because the apps know nothing about a database and neither have a manage.py

Answer (score 0):

Thats because Django is looking for directories when looking for migrations. Eggs are not directories therefore will not find migrations for the apps installed as eggs.

If you tell `makemigrations` to do it for you, you will see an error like (on windows):

`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: C:\\path\\to\\app_egg.egg\\app\\migrations`

I think the best solution is to not use eggs.

Comment: Thanks. We worked around it by moving all migrations into the main project and still using the egg.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm glad you fixed the issue. The moral of the story is eggs can make migrations like eggs :-)